# Should the first page of a thesis chapter have a header and footer?

Tags: thesis, writing

I am writing my Master's thesis. 
I find it unprofessional to prevent the first page of the chapter to take headers and footers.

Should the first page of a thesis chapter have a header and footer?

Comment: not that it matters too much, but you write it is "unprofessional to prevent... to take". This is a double negative. So do you think it's a good idea or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your institution or supervisor have a fixed opinion on this, adhere to this. Otherwise, consider the following:

- Having both, a header and a footer, makes your layout rather crammed, so it’s not a good idea anyway.
- Usually, the header of a page layout contains the page number and the title of the current chapter or section (varying on odd/even pages).
- Usually, the chapter heading is designed in such a manner that it is open to the top.
- In this case, using a header on the first page on a chapter is bad for two reasons:

  1. It breaks the layout of the chapter heading.
  2. Except for the page number, it contains redundant information: Your chapter title and your section title will be on the same page.

  As the page number is rather small, it can be stowed away at the bottom of the page, so it is there for the purposes of citing page numbers. For leafing through the thesis to find a particular page, a gap in the page numbering at the head is not a problem.

Hence it’s quite common in professional typesetting (just look at some textbooks) to omit the header on the first page of a chapter and instead have a solitary page number at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Many universities have quite specific requirements for formatting and layout of theses and dissertations.  You should first check these requirements with your university's graduate college (or whatever entity oversees the approval and publishing of theses/dissertations) before you alter formatting.

Comment: This cannot be emphasized enough. Please follow your university's rules on formatting very carefully when you submit your document.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Instead, I cannot emphasize enough that not all universities have rules on thesis formatting, and thus I think that we should be able to provide more information on the rationale of certain stylistic choices.